# Combining multi one hot encoded columns in pandas dataframe along with removing duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe that looks like this :

```
ID  A B C

1   1 0 0
1   0 1 0
2   1 0 0
```

I want the output to be like this :

```
ID  A B C

1   1 1 0
2   1 0 0
```

Kindly guide how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) with `as_index=False` to get 1 whenever there is at least one 1:

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).max()
```

Output:

```
   ID  A  B  C
0   1  1  1  0
1   2  1  0  0
```